# Can you resize existing widget by updating it?

Tags: android

I have existing widget of a certain size installed on user machine, is it possible to, through an update, change the size of the widget already installed? I noticed that as it it'll just squeeze into existing space.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The best you can do is change the provider name in AndroidManifest (and the provider name of course), then the widget will be automatically removed.

The user then can choose to install your new widget. Of course you can always keep 2 widgets of different sizes.